# Batch Process engineering

Tags: thermodynamics

For a fast chemical reaction where reactant A is fed into an agitated solution of reactant B.

Can the selectivity of the reaction be strongly dependent on the location of the feed pipe outlet?

I am not too sure if specific power input has anything to do with it. I can't seem to understand the principles behind the selectivity. If anyone could help, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Is the system allowed to equilibrate?

Answer (score 0):

If the reaction is potentiated when there's support, the walls could be a way for that species to react more.
Now, you could check if the agitation is right and check for selectivity feeding from the border and from the center, then comparing results.